# For Which $a$ And $b$ Above $\mathbb{Z}_5$ There Are Solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> For which values of $a$ and $b$ above $\mathbb{Z_5}$ the following equations have no solution/one solution, infinite solutions
>
> \begin{cases}
> ax+4y+3z=0   \\
> 2y+3z=1\\
> 3x-bz=3
> \end{cases}

So the matrix is

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    a & 4 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & -b & 3
  \end{array}\right]
$$

After $-\frac{3}{a}R_1+R_3\rightarrow R_3$ and $\frac{6}{a}R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3$ and assuming $a\neq 0$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    a & 4 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -b+\frac{9}{a} & 3+\frac{6}{a}
  \end{array}\right]
$$

So I have no solution if $-b+\frac{9}{a}=0$ and $3+\frac{6}{a}\neq 0$

Infinite solution if $-b+\frac{9}{a}=0$ and $3+\frac{6}{a}=0$

And one solution in all the other cases?

Comment: I do not see how you come up with the last columnn $(0, 0, -b+\frac{9}{a}, 3+\frac{6}{a})$

Comment: @Cornman edtied

Comment: @Cornman sorry typo it is $\frac{6}{a}$ not $-\frac{6}{a}$

Comment: I deleted my comment, since I responded before I saw that you make 2 calculations to come up with your 3rd row.

Answer (score 1):

from the equation (III) we get
$$x=1+\frac{b}{3}z$$
plugg in (I)
$$a+z\left(\frac{ab}{3}+3\right)+4y=0$$
from (II) we have
$$4y=2-6z$$  and we obtain
$$z\left(\frac{ab}{3}-3\right)=-(2+a)$$

Comment: If look for not solution I get $ab=9$ and $a\neq -2$ or $ab=4$ and $a\neq 3$ (mod 5)